# Page reloads before Success message is displayed

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

My code has ajax that makes calls to several asp.net webmethods which in turn post data to the database successfully.

Once a user fills out the form and clicks the submit button, a progress bar is displayed.

Once the process completes, progress bar is hidden and "**Thank you, data successfully added**" message is displayed.

So far, so good.

The issue is that as soon as I added one line of code, `location.reload()` to reload the page after submit, then the success message as well as the progress bar are no longer being displayed.

Any ideas why?

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (confirm('Please verify that your information is correct before submitting. Click Ok to submit, Click Cancel to make additional changes.')) {
        var empComplete = false, sourceComplete = false, spouseComplete = false, dividentComplete = false, reimbursedComplete = false, honorariaComplete = false, giftComplete = false, orgComplete = false, creditorComplete = false;
        function checkComplete() {
            if (empComplete && sourceComplete && spouseComplete && dividentComplete && reimbursedComplete && honorariaComplete && giftComplete && orgComplete && creditorComplete) {
                $("#result").text("Thank you! You have successfully completed this form");
            }
        }

        var $loading = $('#loadingDiv').hide();
        $(document)
            .ajaxStart(function () {
                $loading.show();
            })
            .ajaxStop(function () {
                $loading.hide();
                location.reload();
            });

        $("#result").text("");
        var data = JSON.stringify(getAllEmpData());
        console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'closures.aspx/SaveEmpData',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'empdata': data }),
            async: false,
            success: function () {
                empComplete = true;
                checkComplete();
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error while inserting data");
            }
        });
        var data = JSON.stringify(getAllSourcepData());
        console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'closures.aspx/SaveSourceData',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'empdata': data }),
            success: function () {
                sourceComplete = true;
                checkComplete();
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error while inserting data");
            }
        });
    }
});
...
...
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md pull-center btn-sm" value="Submit" />
<img id="loadingDiv" style="display:none;" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
<output id="result" style="margin-bottom:300px;margin-left:250px;color:#3c890e;font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;"></output>
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave data processing in `success`. But move code for hiding (when all is done) on Ajax's `complete`. For example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'closures.aspx/SaveEmpData',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'empdata': data }),
    async: false,
    success: function () {
        empComplete = true;
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error while inserting data");
    },
    complete: function () {
        checkComplete();
    }
});
```

I can't test the code because it is not complete solution. But I did some changes that might help you:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (confirm('Please verify that your information is correct before submitting. Click Ok to submit, Click Cancel to make additional changes.')) {
        var empComplete = false, sourceComplete = false, spouseComplete = false, dividentComplete = false, reimbursedComplete = false, honorariaComplete = false, giftComplete = false, orgComplete = false, creditorComplete = false;
        function checkComplete() {
            if (empComplete && sourceComplete && spouseComplete && dividentComplete && reimbursedComplete && honorariaComplete && giftComplete && orgComplete && creditorComplete) {
                $("#result").text("Thank you! You have successfully completed this form");
                $loading.hide();
                location.reload();
            }
        }

        var $loading = $('#loadingDiv').hide();

        $("#result").text("");
        var data = JSON.stringify(getAllEmpData());
        console.log(data);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'closures.aspx/SaveEmpData',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'empdata': data }),
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $loading.show();
            },
            success: function () {
                empComplete = true;
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error while inserting data");
            }
        });

        data = JSON.stringify(getAllSourcepData());
        console.log(data);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'closures.aspx/SaveSourceData',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'empdata': data }),
            success: function () {
                sourceComplete = true;
            },
            complete: function () {
                checkComplete();
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error while inserting data");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Alex but it did not work.

Still reloading before message is displayed.

Comment: You have two ajax calls so modify both of them

Comment: I did modify both.

Comment: Oh, I saw that you have location reload on ajaxStop. Move it to complete too

Comment: Add to both ajax calls?

I added it to the last one but it still did not work.

Comment: To be honest, you should add reload method to complete operation. In your case it is checkSuccess. Try to reduce repeated code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138558/discussion-between-alex-slipknot-and-kenny).